# Querying an array of a Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

At the moment, I am working on a project that I have been doing in an online bootcamp. This is basically a review site for campgrounds (I'm sure there'll be a lot of people who know what I mean). Essentially, you can register yourself, you can create campsites and then you can review others.

I am using a mongo database (as is covered in this course).

Currently, I am working on a route whereby the user is able to delete his/her profile. The user also is able to successfully delete other campground contributions and reviews. However, the average rating of a campground is determined from the campground model. Whenever someone reviews a campground, their review (the rating, comment, name, user id, date etc.)

Below is a view of the **campground model**:

```
const campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String, 
        required: "This field cannot be left blank"
    },
    image: String, 
    imageId: String, 
    description: String,
    price: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now}, 
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: "User", 
        }, 
        username: String
    },
    comments: [
        {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "Comment"
        }
    ],
    slug: {
        type: String, 
        unique: true, 
        trim: true
    },
    reviews: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: "Review"
        }
    ], 
    rating: {
        type: Number, 
        default: 0
    }
});
```

Below is the model for the **reviews**:

```
var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    rating:{
        //set the field type
        type: Number, 

        //Making the star rating required
        required: "Please provide a rating (1 to 5 stars)", 

        //Define minimum and maximum values:
        min: 1, 
        max: 5,

        //Add validation to ensure that entry is an integer: 
        validate:{
            validator: Number.isInteger, 
            message: "{VALUE} is not an integer value"
        }
    }, 
    text:{
        type: String, 
    },
    author: {
        id:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, 
            ref: "User"
        }, 
        username: String
    }, 
    campground: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, 
        ref: "Campground", 
    }
}, {
    //timestamps: mongoose assings createdAt and updatedAt to the schema. 
    timestamps:true
});
```

Now, whenever I delete a user profile, the reviews in the array are removed (**great**), however I need to link up to the campground to run a function to give them an appropriate rating.

Below is the route for to delete the user:

```
router.delete("/users/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res)=>{
    User.findById(req.params.id, (err, user)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err); 
            req.flash("err", "UNABLE TO DELETE PROFILE " + err.message)
        }

        // delete campgrounds - finds campgrounds based on author.id and deletes them 
        Campground.deleteMany({"author.id": user.id}, (err)=>{ 
            if(err){
                console.log(err); 
            } 
        }); 

        //delete reviews - finds reviews based on author.id and deletes them 
        Review.deleteMany({"author.id": user.id}, (err)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }


    // WHERE I'M STUCK 
         Campground.findOne( { reveiws: {"author.id":user.id} }, {new: true}). exec((err, campground)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log("ERROR:  " + err.message); 
                } else{  
                    console.log("CAMPGROUND:  " + campground); 
                }
                });

          }); 

        //delete profile picture from cloudinary
        try{
            cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(user.imageId);
            user.remove();
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");  
        } catch(err){
            if(err){
                req.flash("error", err.message);
                return res.redirect("back");  
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

In summary, all I need to do is query the campgrounds database to find campgrounds that have had a review by the user who is deleting their profile.

Answer (score 0):

you should give user id as user._id instead of user.id